# HTML input type="date" value format

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the default  for a date field in a form and this outputs a value of "YYYY-MM-DD" however for the query I am running with the form I need the format "YYYY,MM,DD".

Is there an easy way with javascript to parse this input fields value to fit the second format?

Thank you.

Comment: So all you need to do is replace the dashes with commas. That should be easy enough to research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse it with javascript before you submit it, yes.  Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gasm6d0e/

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="bday" value="2010-10-01">
```

Javascript/JQuery

```
alert($("#bday").val().replace(/-/g,","));
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to parse it using the substr function:

```
function reorder_date(string)
    {   
    year = string.substr(0,4);
    month = string.substr(5,2);
    day = string.substr(8,2);
    next_string= year + "," + month + "," + day;
    return next_string;
    }
```